# does jquery remove css style?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tying to troubleshoot a problem with my css. I have the following div tag:

```
<div class="span1" id="progress-indicator" style="text-align:left; border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Later on in my script section of the code, I do something like this:

```
 $('#progress-indicator').html("saving changes....");
```

When you use the html() method, is it only changing the space between the opening / closing div tags or does it change the attributes of the div tag? 
I'm asking because once this jquery is called, the size of the div seems bigger than a span1 div should be.

Thanks.

Comment: No `.html` will not alter the attributes of an element.

Comment: You might have some styles applied that don't appear until there's some actual content in the div.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong? You don't apply any styles (in this code) to *set* the size of the div. Also you're calling a `div` "span1"? That's not confusing at all...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/ it tells you all you need to know about this jquery method. the jquery docs are your friend... google is an even better friend

Comment: Dave, that's standard Bootstrap class usage. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: not everyone knows bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery documentation only mentions that the content is affected:
http://api.jquery.com/html/

I quote: "Description: Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements."

An example of the jquery documentation:

```
$('div.demo-container')
    .html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');
```

That line of code will replace everything inside :

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>
</div>
```

I set up an example: http://jsfiddle.net/caZtd/

Now if you click the progress-indicator div and you inspect the element before and after clicking (with firebug in firefox of the chrome developer tools), you will see that there is no difference in the html markup whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks. I did take a look at the jquery documentation but thought there was something I misunderstood.  I'll keep hunting to find the bug